# Vertical seekbar turns transparent on API25-

Tags: android, android-seekbar, android-vertical-seekbar

I'm using [aosp implementation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/MusicFX/+/master/src/com/android/musicfx/SeekBarRotator.java) for vertical seekbar and it works just fine on API 26+ but on lower APIs its accent turns transparent (doesn't pick up the app's accent colour), any ideas on what could be causing this issue?

The seekbars are used inside windowmanager that has its own theme set when view is expanded/created which extends the parent AppTheme where accent colour is set, should I also set accent colour in the child theme?

Shreenshots: 
On API 27:
[image: API27]

On API 24:
[image: API24]

Comment: A screenshot which shows the problem better will be really good : )

Comment: @hardartcore done

Comment: In my opinion it's not transparent, it's just black. Try to change the background color to see if that's the problem and I will help you to resolve that issue with themes. : )

Comment: My app has light and dark theme and results are the same on both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to explicitly set the accent color for it pick it up, seems like it doesn't automatically inherit it from the theme on older APIs